# Properties of k-linear form

Tags: multilinear-algebra

I would like to know if this is correct:

Let be $f:V\times V\times\text{ }...\times V\rightarrow W $ a symetric k-linear  form. If $f(v,..,v)=f\cdot v^k=0,\forall v\in V$, then $f=0$.

I proved this for k=2, but I don't know if it's worth it in general.

Comment: What are $\dim V$ und $\dim W$?

Comment: finite dimension.

Comment: This is true at least in characteristic $0$. It follows from a generalization of the polarization identity for inner products, which can be stated in a few different ways. You can also do it by proving that the symmetric power $S^k(V)$ is generated by tensors of the form $v^k$.